# Spark RDDs with shared pointers within each partition (and the magic number 200??)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I am trying to persist a spark RDD in which the elements of each partition all share access to a single, large object. However, this object seems get stored in memory several times. Reducing my problem down to the toy case of just a single partition with only 200 elements:

```scala
val nElements = 200
class Elem(val s:Array[Int])

val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(1)).mapPartitions( _ => {
    val sharedArray = Array.ofDim[Int](10000000) // Should require ~40MB
    (1 to nElements).toIterator.map(i => new Elem(sharedArray))
}).cache()

rdd.count() //force computation
```

This consumes the expected amount of memory, as seen in the logs:

> *storage.MemoryStore: Block rdd_1_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 38.2 MB, free 5.7 GB)*

However, 200 is the maximum number of elements for which this is so. Setting `nElements=201` yields:

> *storage.MemoryStore: Block rdd_1_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 76.7 MB, free 5.7 GB)*

What causes this? Where does this magic number 200 come from, and how can I increase it?

---

**EDIT FOR CLARIFICATIONS**:

Adding a println to the function reveals that it is indeed called only once. Furthermore, running:

```
rdd.map(_.s.hashCode).min == rdd.map(_.s.hashCode).max  // returns true
```

..reveals that all 10000000 elements do indeed point to the same object, and so the data structure essentially behaves correctly. The problem comes when nExamples is much larger (e.g. 20000), and so it cannot persist.

> *storage.MemoryStore: Not enough space to cache rdd_1_0 in memory! (computed 6.1 GB so far)*

When I set `nExamples=500` it successfully persists the rdd in memory saying *estimated size 1907.4 MB*, but I can see that the actual increase in my memory usage is far less than this.

Comment: have you tried setting  `preservesPartitioning = true`? Is it the same behavior?

Comment: Just gave it a go, and yep. No difference.

Comment: Could you put a `println` inside the function given to `mapPartitions`? I wonder if it gets called twice. Also, what does `rdd.foreach(x => println(x))` look like? The same pointer for each element?

Comment: The function only gets called once. And yes, the same pointer for each element.

Comment: It seems like the data structure is acting as it should and so this wouldn't be a problem at all except that, as nElements becomes much larger (as I want it to be), spark loses the ability to persist. Instead it just complains: Not enough space to cache rdd_1_0 in memory! (computed 6.1 GB so far)

Answer (score 0):

For anybody stumbling upon this in the future, I eventually came up with a super hacky solution (though I'd still be happy to hear a better one). Instead of using rdd.cache(), I define:

```
def cached[T: ClassTag](rdd:RDD[T]) = {
    rdd.mapPartitions(p => 
        Iterator(p.toSeq)
    ).cache().mapPartitions(p =>
        p.next().toIterator
    )
}
```

so that `cached(rdd)` returns an RDD that is generated from a 'cached' List